# Display JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON format like this returned via a ajax call

```
{
    "user_page_id":"36",
    "user_page_name":"yahoo",
    "page_template_name":"",
    "page_avatar":"false",
    "page_address":" Yahoo Pvt Limited,Yahoo CORP,US",
    "page_country":"US",
    "page_city":"Newyork",
    "page_pincode":"22222222223",
    "page_email":"x@y",
    "page_mob":"34654564654",
    "page_landline":"235449898544584",
    "page_profile":"yes",
    "page_meta_tags":" yahoo,yahoo,yahoo",
    "page_facebook_username":"yahoo",
    "page_twitter_link":"yahoo",
    "page_state":"Newyork state"
}
```

and this is my call

```
$.get(url,{parameters},function(data){
    alert(data.user_page_name);  //return undefined    
});
```

How can i get the value of `user_page_name` and others ?

Thank you.

Note : `The Question is SOLVED`

Comment: You need to specify JSON as the return type

Comment: @Pekka ,waaav ,`SOLVED`,i forgot that and searching alot...thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "GET",
  data: parameters,
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function(data){
    alert(data.user_page_name); 
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is not working because the format of your data is not JSON.

You should use the JQuery function [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The data can be retrieved very easily by doing something like this:

```
$.get(url,{parameters},function(data){
    alert(data["user_page_id"]);
    alert(data["user_page_name"]);
});
```